# Auto-fill on WiFi Captive Portal

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal, auto-fill

Is there a way to auto-fill the username/password when connecting to a Wifi's Captive Portal? If possible, I would like a method that does not require root access.
The portal opens with the system's default "HTML viewer" and not with Firefox/Chrome which would solve the problem since these browsers offer auto-fill.

This question has been asked in the past and users suggested:

- [Captive Portal Controller](https://github.com/MuntashirAkon/CaptivePortalController) app (but requires root)
- [CaptivePortalLogin](https://f-droid.org/packages/com.juliansparber.captiveportallogin/) app which claims to do this, but is in beta and does not seem to work for me.

Version: Android 11 / MIUI 12.5